# Curve fitting an equation to remove irrationals

Tags: fitting

Suppose I have a long equation with square roots and various trigonometric functions. Is there a way to approximate this function (over a fixed range) by curve fitting? My reading is that curve fitting is often used to regress over data points. In this case, the input would be a function though. Are there ways to force curve fitting use "simpler" integer functions? For instance, disallow the use of square roots or other irrational functions.

Any thought appreciated

Comment: You can calculate values of your function on an appropriate grid, then feed those to e.g. `NonlinearModelFit`. You will have to provide a model function to fit those points to, so you have full freedom to choose which functions appear in your model.

Comment: See [`FindFormula`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html) (or [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)).

Comment: Use `FunctionInterpolation` to get a piecewise polynomial interpolation.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've just tried `FunctionInterpolation`, but how do I obtain the equation for the `InterpolatingFunction` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very familiar with this area, but I think you may be looking for the [FunctionApproximations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FunctionApproximations/guide/FunctionApproximationsPackage.html) package, or maybe [`PadeApproximant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadeApproximant.html).

For example, let us approximate the function

```
f[x_] := Cos[x] + Sqrt[x]
```

with rational expressions on the interval $[0,2]$.

```
approx = EconomizedRationalApproximation[f[x], {x, {0, 2}, 2, 2}];
Plot[{f[x], approx} // Evaluate, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

There are several other approximation methods in the package.

You may want to numericize the result using `N[approx] // Simplify`, as the exact coefficients are complicated.